# attribue with dynamic variable name

Tags: python

another dynamic variable question, but different from other seen imho.

```
class MyClass:
    myvarA="alfa"
    myvarB="beta"
    myvarC="gamma"

myobj=MyClass()
for var in ["A", "B", "C"]:
    print("{}\n".format("myobj.myvar{}".format(var)))
```

My goal: print all attributes values in oneline using format myvar+variable as var name.

print in last line, prints "myobj.myvarA..B..C"  instead of values

many thanks

Comment: why do you want to do that?

Comment: because i have a many attr with similar name like example and per each attr i have to do some actions, so i don't want to copy paste each action but calls all attrs with similar name

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You generally don't want to do that, you'll want to use a dict if you need "dynamic variable names".

Anyway, you can do this with [`getattr()`](https://docs.python.org/3.9/library/functions.html#getattr):

```
class MyClass:
    myvarA = "alfa"
    myvarB = "beta"
    myvarC = "gamma"


myobj = MyClass()
for var in ["A", "B", "C"]:
    var_name = f"myvar{var}"
    print(getattr(myobj, var_name))
```

Comment: I've seen replies to similar question with dict answer, but everyone build a dict with k,v that' is not what i need, i need cycle througn attrs without specify myvarA myvarB myvarC but myvar{variable_part}

Comment: Quoting your other comment, "i have a many attr with similar name like example" and you'd need to iterate over them – you do really need a dict, not many attributes.

Comment: I've seen many times, about question similar to this, things like "You generally don't want to do that", ok please @AKX why? For OOP? change all attrs to dict could be a lot of work, and involve many parts of the program, worth a wile?

Comment: It's a philosophical difference – attributes are "meant" to be more concrete and well-defined than a dict which is a "bag" of keys and values associated with them. If you need "dynamic fields", that generally means you'd want a dict. As an aside, slotsless objects are internally backed by dicts (see the `__dict__` attribute of instances)...